# Building tree from array

Tags: arrays, recursion, tree, preorder

I was asked to build a tree from an array where each element contained  the data for the node and the level of the node within the tree. The array was a preorder traversal of the node.

I think my solution was wrong (or at least not the best way of doing it) but I'm not sure why and what the right solution would be.

My approach was to start with level 0 on the first call to the function and then loop through the array and when I found anything with a level that is exactly 1 greater than the level in the current recursive call, I make a recursive call that takes the array starting at the index of that element and increment level. Then, the result of that recursive call would be the child.

I also check if the level of the element in the array is equal to the level in the current recursive call- if so, I break out of the loop because it would be my sibling and I don't want to return my sibling because my parent will take care of that in another recursive call.

Does that make any sense? What would I need to change to answer this question correctly?

Comment: Hint:  You don't need recursion.  If I'm reading your question correctly, the array is already in a preorder traversal of the tree.

Comment: 2nd hint:  You should read the very excellent article on [how to ask technical questions](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  It will help you write better questions.  (Pasting some code would have helped).

Comment: I shared what I've tried by describing the algorithm I came up with and tried to use. I didn't include the code because I was looking for a flaw in my algorithm, not in my code, and I wasn't expecting an answer that would include code.

Comment: Was the original tree that was used to create the array sorted (was it a search tree)? Is the tree a binary tree?

Comment: No- it's not necessarily sorted or binary.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how recursion is not necessary. If I use recursion, I can assign all the children I find to the root node at the current recursive call. Otherwise, I can't see a good way of knowing which parent to add each child to.